# Importrange a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

My question is:

I've a lot of files, like 30+, that I need to maintain periodically.
My idea was to create a master file, where I will modify formulas only 1 time, and then the formulas will be copied automatically to those files.
How is this possible? I thought about some kind of importrange combination but it doesn't make the formula run, it just imports the "numbers".

Update:

Ok I'll try to make it clear. I've many files that all look the same, as this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1arbr1H5Pt-eye5MBv-RrzMy1hrREY4ZE9SNy6rHYFJE/edit#gid=0 (Master) and this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hwq826njON8qzCu7siHDNjKLGVXRblFxhwdcN1G_gdo/edit#gid=0 (Slave) In Cell A1, Slave is importing the result of A1 in Master. But what I want to achieve is to import the formula, not the result. So Slave will do exactly what Master do, with is own Data on its column D. , as u could see now it isn't.

If Master A1 Sum D1:D, Slave A1 should do the same with its D1:D but when I decide to write another formula in MasterA1, it should as well change with its own reference in all the slaves

Comment: Make 3 sample sheets to simulate what you are talking about. Two with the data and One with the importrange then post the links here with the sample data and desired output (behavior your want) + the output you currently have, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? ImportRange is good enough to view data, are you saying you want to edit the data? If you want to edit the data why not put all 30+ sheets in one giant sheet and then importrange them out for viewing purposes, sounds like you are doing things backwards.

Comment: Ok I'll try to make it clear. I've many files that all look the same, as this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1arbr1H5Pt-eye5MBv-RrzMy1hrREY4ZE9SNy6rHYFJE/edit#gid=0 (Master)

and this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hwq826njON8qzCu7siHDNjKLGVXRblFxhwdcN1G_gdo/edit#gid=0 (Slave)

In Cell A1, Slave is importing the result of A1 in Master. But what I want to achieve is to import the formula, not the result. So Slave will do exactly what Master do, with is own Data on it's column D. , as u could see now it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Tl;Dr: This is possible  by using Google Apps Script and/or the Google Sheets API

There isn't a "built-in" function like IMPORTRANGE that updates the formulas of dependent spreadsheets based on a "master" spreadsheet.

You could develop or borrow an algorithm (step by step instructions) and implement that algorithm using your preferred programming "something" like Google Apps Script / JavaScript, Python, Java or find someone that already did that or is available to do that for you.

Reference
https://developers.google.com/sheets

Comment: ty but...something more specific? That script was a possible answer is a little generic...exactly what kind of function should I check? ty

Comment: @SimoneRosmarino his answer was as specific as your question.

Comment: @SimoneRosmarino I extended a bit my answer. If you need a more detailed answer, please make a new more detailed question (see [ask]) by the other hand if you need a software recommendation, please ask for it in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com as that is off-topic on this site.

Comment: @SimoneRosmarino Importrange imports the values only. To achieve what you seek you must re-think your ingeneering and find a different way to achieve your goal